# Extracting only a part of a json response with jmeter and use it in beanshell post processor

Tags: json, jmeter, response, beanshell

While checking the CPU usage through a `jmeter` thread, I get below response,

> “response":"%Cpu(s): 93.9 us, 6.1 sy, 0.0 ni, 0.0 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi,
>   0.0 si, 0.0 st\n","exitValue":0}

in my case I want to filter only the us value from the response and I need to verify whether it exceeded a particular limit.(eg. us value > 70)

Can anyone suggest me a method in `jmeter` through which I can store the us value in a variable and use that value in a bean shell post processor?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get this `93.9` value it can be done with [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). The relevant Regular Expression would be something like:

```
%Cpu\(s\): (.+?) us
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor View Results Tree]

Whole Regular Expression Extractor configuration would be something like:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression]

---

Once you extract the value you will be able to access it as :

```
double cpu = Double.parseDouble(vars.get("cpu"));
```

---

Be aware that [using Beanshell for scripting is a some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language instead.